# Accessing Request.Form.Files throws Exception System.io.InvalidDataException

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, summernote

As mentioned in my Title, upon accessing Request.Form.Files, the application throws the exception

`System.Io.InvalidDataException: "Multipart body length limit 16384 exceeded" in an Asp.Net Core 2.0.0 Web Application.` The Application I am working on is an Asp.Net Core MVC Web Application. I am using Summernote as my WYSIWYG Text-Editor. There I enabled the Feature to upload Images (s. my Javascript). This worked fine, until I needed to implement another uploader to upload text files like .pdf, txt, doc.
The Error appears while using the summernote texteditor, either with the "standard" upload button or a custom pdf uplader button (s. C# Code). The Image functionality worked fine, until I (tried) to implement the new pdf file uploader. At first my Error looked pretty basic because it was clear, that the files I tried to upload where bigger than 16kb (Asp.Net Cores Uploadlimit), so I tried the "common" methods (s. below) to fix this error, that are found on Stack Overflow and similar sites:

```
    services.Configure<FormOptions>(x =>
    {
        x.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
        x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = long.MaxValue;
        x.MemoryBufferThreshold = 20;
    });
```

or

```
public class RequestFormSizeLimitAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter, IOrderedFilter
{
    public int Order { get; }
    private readonly FormOptions _formOptions;

    public RequestFormSizeLimitAttribute(int valueCountLimit)
    {
        _formOptions = new FormOptions()
        {

            ValueCountLimit = valueCountLimit,
            KeyLengthLimit = valueCountLimit
        };
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var features = context.HttpContext.Features;
        var formFeature = features.Get<IFormFeature>();

        if (formFeature == null || formFeature.Form == null)
        {
            // Request form has not been read yet, so set the limits
            features.Set(new FormFeature(context.HttpContext.Request, _formOptions));
        }
    }


}
```

or

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

however none of these Methods fixed my Error.
First of all my Jquery Code:

```
//For Image Uploading
function sendFiles(file) {
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("file", file);
    data.append('divisionId', $('#divisionId').val());
    $.ajax({
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api/File/UploadImageAjax",
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (image) {
            if (image !== "Error") {
                var picture = $(image);
                $('#summernote').summernote("insertNode", picture[0]);
            } else {
                bootbox.alert("Fehler beim hochladen des Bildes.");
            }
        }
    });
}

//For PDF-File Upload
$('#btnUpload').on('click', function (e) {
        var validation = validator.form();
        e.preventDefault();
        if (validation) {
            var data = new FormData();
            var text = document.getElementById('pdfText').value;
            var fileSelect = document.getElementById('pdfFile');
            data.append('linkName', text);
            data.append('divisionId', $('#divisionId').val());
            var files = fileSelect.files;
            data.append('file', files[0]);
            closeModal();
            $.ajax({
                data: data,
                type: "POST",
                url: "/api/File/UploadTextFileAjax",
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (file) {
                    var atag = document.createElement('a');
                    atag.setAttribute('href', file.absoulutePath);
                    atag.setAttribute('id', file.fileId);
                    atag.innerHtml = file.linkText;
                    $('#summernote').summernote('insertNode', atag);
                },
                error: function(respons) {
                    bootbox.alert("Fehler beim Speichern der Text Datei.");
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

And finally my C# Code from the Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        [RequestFormSizeLimit(valueCountLimit: 2147483647)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadImageAjax()
        {
            //Exception thrown here.
            var files = Request.Form.Files;
            var request = Request.Form.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Key == "divisionId");
            var divisionName = await GetDivisionNameAsync(request);
            if (divisionName != null)
            {
                var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
                if (files.Count == 1 && user != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                    {
                        var file = files[i];
                        if (TestImageFileName(file))
                        {
                            var path = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.ToString().Trim('"');
                            var fileName = $@"\images\Sportarten\{divisionName}\{path}";
                            if (!await _imageHandler.IsImageInDbAsync(fileName))
                            {
                                path = _hosting.WebRootPath + fileName;
                                using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(path))
                                {
                                    await file.CopyToAsync(fs);
                                    await fs.FlushAsync();
                                }
                                var image = new ImageViewModel { FileName = file.FileName, AbsolutePath = fileName, AspNetUserId = user.Id, FullPath = path };
                                var imageId = await _imageHandler.AddImageAsync(image);
                                var imageNode = $@"<img id='{imageId}' src='{fileName}' class='img-responsive'/>";
                                return Json(imageNode);
                            }
                            var id = await _imageHandler.GetImageIdbyNameAsync(path);
                            var node = $@"<img id='{id}' src='{fileName}' class='img-responsive'/>";
                            return Json(node);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return BadRequest("Error");
        }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadTextFileAjax()
    {
        //Exception thrown here.
        var files = Request.Form.Files;
        var request = Request.Form.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Key == "divisionId");
        var divisionName = await GetDivisionNameAsync(request);
        var linkText = Request.Form.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Key == "linkName").Value.ToString();
        if (linkText != null && divisionName != null)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
            if (files.Count == 1 && user != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                {
                    var file = files[i];
                    if (TestTextFileName(file))
                    {
                        var path = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.ToString().Trim('"');
                        var fileName = $@"\files\Sportarten\{divisionName}\{path}";
                        if (await _file.IsFileInDb(fileName))
                        {
                            path = _hosting.WebRootPath + fileName;
                            using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(path))
                            {
                                await file.CopyToAsync(fs);
                                await fs.FlushAsync();
                            }
                            var textFile = new FileViewModel
                            {
                                AbsolutePath = fileName,
                                AspNetUserId = user.Id,
                                FileName = file.FileName,
                                FullPath = path
                            };
                            var fileId = await _file.AddFile(textFile);
                            return Ok(new {absolutePath = path, fileId = fileId, linkText = linkText});
                        }
                        var oldText = await _file.FindFilebyName(path);
                        return Ok(new { absolutePath = oldText.AbsolutePath, fileId = oldText.FileId, linkText = linkText });
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        return BadRequest("Error");
    }
```

At last here is my Stacktrace I get, when the error is thrown(sorry for the bad quality):
[Full Stacktrace of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Mp8y.png)

Comment: You have a lot of possible fixes, but it's often helpful to understand the problem first.  Please include the full stack trace as well as your code nearest to where the exception was thrown.  It sounds like this is a web application you wrote, if not you might want to point that out.  I can't tell if you're developing an application on top of summernote or using summernote and getting this error?  Or just using summernote to write some other application...